# java code gives error in mongodb while compiling

Tags: java, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am new to mongodb and i have the following code

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class getAssets{



    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>() {
       @Override
       public void apply(final Document document) {
           System.out.println(document.toJson());
       }
    };

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("asset");


        BasicDBList statusList = new BasicDBList();
        statusList.add("1");
        statusList.add("2");
        statusList.add("3");
        DBObject statusInClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", statusList);  

        BasicDBList idList = new BasicDBList();
        idList.add("123");
        DBObject siteIdInClause = new BasicDBObject("$in", idList); 

        DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("asset.status", statusInClause);
        fields.put("asset.siteid", siteIdInClause);


        DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$asset");
        DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", fields); 

        AggregateIterable<Document> aggr = coll.aggregate(asList(unwind, match));

        aggr.forEach(printBlock);
        mongoClient.close();
    }



}
```

And i am getting the following error while compling

```
C:\MongoDB\java>javac -cp .;mongo-java-driver-3.4.1.jar getAssets.java
getAssets.java:46: error: no suitable method found for aggregate(List<DBObject>)
                AggregateIterable<Document> aggr = coll.aggregate(asList(unwind, match));
                                                       ^
    method MongoCollection.<TResult>aggregate(List<? extends Bson>,Class<TResult>) is not applicable
      (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method MongoCollection.aggregate(List<? extends Bson>) is not applicable
      (actual argument List<DBObject> cannot be converted to List<? extends Bson> by method invocation conversion)
  where TResult is a type-variable:
    TResult extends Object declared in method <TResult>aggregate(List<? extends Bson>,Class<TResult>)
1 error
```

**Note : Using mongo 3.4.1**

New Code :

```
import com.mongodb.*;
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import static java.util.Arrays;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class getAssets{



    public static void main( String args[] ){

        Block<Document> printBlock = new Block<Document>() {
       @Override
       public void apply(final Document document) {
           System.out.println(document.toJson());
       }
    };

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("asset");


        Document unwind = new Document("$unwind", "$dp.asset");
        Document match  = new Document("$match", new Document("$dp.asset.status", new Document("$in", new String[]{"ACTIVE", "LIMITEDUSE", "OPERATING"})).
             append("$dp.asset.siteid", new Document("$in", new String[]{"BEDFORD"})));

        AggregateIterable<Document> aggr = coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(unwind, match));

        aggr.forEach(printBlock);
        mongoClient.close();
    }



}
```

Compiles with no error but runtime error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.BsonDocument.clone()Lorg/bson/BsonDocument;
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:146)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.createClientMetadataDocument(ClientMetadataHelper.java:136)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.<init>(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:68)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:360)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>(SingleServerCluster.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:293)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:288)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:156)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:146)
    at getAssets.main(getAssets.java:20)
```

Comment: Any luck solving this? Have the exact same error driver 3.8.0 and mongo 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

For me , I resolved this error  by using mongodb driver 3.6.4
Add this in your dependency(gradle for example)

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.6.4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to manage my dependencies and I noticed that I had the MongoDB bson library listed twice in my libraries (once as org.mongo:bson:3.0.0 and also as org.mongo:bson:Latest). I deleted the "Latest" entry and the error went away.